# Angular 2 routing refreshing parent

Tags: angular, routes

In my Angular application I'm using relative routes to navigate between components. I have a parent component which displays a list of items and a child component to edit that component. The problem is that when I edit an item and navigate back to display the whole list, I have to refresh the page to see modifications.

```
const aoRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/ao/list",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "ao",
    component: AppelOffreComponent,
    children: [
    
      {
        path: "list",
        component: ListAoComponent,
        children: [
         
          {
            path: "edit/:ao_id",
            component: EditAoComponent
          },
..
];
```

my component is:

```
this._aoService
          .updateAO(appelOffre)
    
          .subscribe(success => {
            this.statusCode = success;
            this.loading = false;
          }, error => (this.statusCode = error));
    
        this.router.navigate(["../../"], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: Are you using a snapshot of the route, or the observable route?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this._aoService.getAOById(params["ao_id"]))
      .subscribe(selected => {
        (this.selectedAo = selected), this.setFormValues();
      });
    //
  }

Comment: are you using data resolvers?

Comment: i'm using observable in my service component: updateAO(ao: AppelOffre): Observable<number> {
    const headers = new Headers();
 
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
      .put(this.updateAoUrl, ao, options)
      .map(success => success.status)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You need a more permanent stream so that when components subscribe to the `status$` observable they get the updated value (from the http call) when the update occurs. The `shareReplay` ensures that even late subscribers are notified of the event.

For example:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


export class AoService {
    status$: Observable<number>;
    _status: Subject<AppelOffre>;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
         this._status = new Subject<AppelOffre>();
         this.status$ = this._status.switchMap(t=> {
              const headers = new Headers(); 
              const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
              return this.http.put(this.updateAoUrl, ao, options)
                .map(success => success.status).catch(this.handleError); 
         }).shareReplay(1);
    }
    update(ao: AppelOffre) {
        this._status.next(ao);
    }
}
```

With this solution, you just need to subscribe to the status event and call update:

```
status: number;
constructor(private aoService: AoService) {
    this.aoService.status$.subscribe(t=> {
       this.status = t;
    });
    this.aoService.update();
}
```

You only need to call `update()` in one place. It would be more useful if the `status$` observable returned data rather than a status code. But its up to you.